# How to complex filter input in javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I wonder if it's possible to filter an input content like this one.

My input accept 16 chars, which have a : separating them into 4 groups:

`0123:0055:02AC:01FA`

As you can see I separated them in 4 groups because I will use these values later, so I need them separated, but I want to filter the input with the mininum value being `0001:0001:0001:0001` and maximum `0FFF:00FF:0FFF:02FF`

I already do a check to see if the input is the valid chars like A-F-09.

It is possible to do that?

```js
$('.entry').keyup(function(e) {
    var val =  $(this).val().toUpperCase().replace(/[^a-fA-F0-9:]+/,"");
    $(this).val(val);
    val = $(this).val().split(":").join("");
    if (val.length > 0) {
      val = val.match(new RegExp('.{1,4}', 'g')).join(":");
    }
    if (val.length >= 0) {
      $('.clearga').show();
    }
    $(this).val(val);
    var galacticCoords = val;
    console.log(galacticCoords);
    var [A, B, C, D] = galacticCoords.split(":");
    
    if (galacticCoords.length == 19) {
      console.log(galacticCoords+" True");
      $('.result').html(galacticCoords);
      $('.value-a').html(A);
      $('.value-b').html(B);
      $('.value-c').html(C);
      $('.value-d').html(D);
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
<input class="entry" placeholder="000F:000F:000F:000F" maxlength="19">

<div class="result"></div>
<div class="block">Value A:<span class="value-a"></span></div>
<div class="block">Value B:<span class="value-b"></span></div>
<div class="block">Value C:<span class="value-c"></span></div>
<div class="block">Value D:<span class="value-d"></span></div>

</body>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if it's what i think it is then it's base 16 numbers, two bytes per each section, which you can do by converting each to an integer and checking it's range.

```
const range = [2095, 256, 2095, 767];
str.split(':').forEach((val, index) => {
var n = parseInt(val, 16);
   if (n > range[index]){ 
      // .. do something
   }
})
```

edit: made a function

```
function filter(str){
    var ranges = [4095, 255, 4095, 767];
    var n;

    return (str.split(':').map((val, index) => {
        n = parseInt(val, 16);
        if (n < 1) return '0001';
        else if (n > ranges[index]) return '0'+ranges[index].toString(16);
        else return val;
    })).join(':')
}
```

Comment: Okay, let me try. But isn't 0FFF = 4095 and 00FF = 255 or am I converting it wrong?

Comment: @RogerHN you are right, i have actually made a quick function for this. check it out above. if this is the correct answer i would appriciate checking my ans as correct

Comment: Okay, can you help me apply this function to my input example? I want to use it together with the regex which filter the input. It's possible?

Comment: run the function i  gave you with the completed text and it will filter it and return a sanitized string back. if you need to change the values as they are being types then my function has to be changed around.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I meant, sorry. I want to validate on keyup like the previous one. It's possible?

Comment: yes it's possible. user enters letter -> letter gets filtered through regex -> every 4 valid letters you range check and edit the string accordingly.